# How do I increase the timeout for Visual Studio predefined table adapters in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, tableadapter

I have used Visual Studio to predefine a DataSet and a series of tableadapters for querying data from SQL Server. Despite modifying my connection string to preset my timeout, the table adapter timeouts after 30 seconds. If I do the following:

```
myTableAdapterClass myTableAdapter = new myTableAdapterClass
myTableAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 600;
```

It says that myTableAdapter is null. But the only command that will be executing with my table adapter is myTableAdapter.Fill. By then it is too late. How can I prepare my table adapter to increase its timeout?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the code:

```
myTableAdapter.Adapter.InsertCommand.CommandTimeout = {some value in secs};
```

For your insert operations like the one you mentioned (myTableAdapter.Fill)

The one that you are using:

```
myTableAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = {some value in secs};
```

Is only for Read (Select) operations.

And in case you need to set a timeout for update operations:

```
myTableAdapter.Adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandTimeout = {some value in secs};
```

Comment: I tried that. It says that the tableadapter is null. I cannot set that value, despite my best efforts.

Comment: Have you initiated the Adapter property of the myTableAdapter class? Can you paste the code of your myTableAdapterClass?

Comment: How do I initialize the adapter other than what I did above?